# popup not close in same button click function in jquery

Tags: jquery, popup

i am trying to onclick on same button hide my popup please suggest me, this only for open but not close in same onclick button. 
Html:-

```
<div class="abcdatacontrolPopupControl">
        <input type="button" id="ddsdsdsNotificationcheck" class="Notification" title="xyz Notification" onclick="abcNotification('close')" />
        <div id="sdffdfdNotification" class="sdfbcContentCtr">

        </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery:-

```
function abcNotification(DisplayLoadingPanel) {
        if (DisplayLoadingPanel) {
            $("#LoadingPanel").css("display", "block");
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "/xyz/abcdefUrl",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            Async: true,
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                if (DisplayLoadingPanel) {
                    $("#LoadingPanel").css("display", "none");
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                if (DisplayLoadingPanel) {
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about DisplayLoadingPanel popup?

Comment: @JitendraRangpariya .abcdatacontrolPopupControl this class div in my popup content and sdffdfdNotification this my popup content div

Comment: I can guess one issue, you should pass true or false as parameter for abcNotification('true') so you can load your LoadingPanel. Regards popup, If you are using jquery popup then you should use something like $('.abcdatacontrolPopupControl').dialog('close'); OR $('.abcdatacontrolPopupControl').dialog('open');

Comment: you mean set both status check

Comment: No you can just try as per @Khang answer but can you post more code/information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes in jquery:-

```
  function abcNotification(DisplayLoadingPanel) {
            if (DisplayLoadingPanel) {
                $("#LoadingPanel").css("display", "block");
            }
            if ($(".sdfbcContentCtr").css("display") == "block") {
                   $("#sdffdfdNotification").hide('fast');
            }
            else {
                 $(".sdfbcContentCtr").css("display", "block");
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "/xyz/abcdefUrl",
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                Async: true,
                data: {},
                success: function (data) {
                    if (DisplayLoadingPanel) {
                        $("#LoadingPanel").css("display", "none");
                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    if (DisplayLoadingPanel) {
                    }
                }
            });
    }
 $("body").click(function () {
       $("#sdffdfdNotification").fadeOut().css("display", "none");
    });
    $(".sdfbcContentCtr").click(function (e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Comment: @JitendraRangpariya same button click issue is resolved and but outside click popup is open

Answer (score 0):

You can use "$("#LoadingPanel").is(":visible")" to check your popup is close or is open
if is open -> close
if is close -> open

Comment: this only for visible